# Regular Expression help needed for extracting text from lines

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text:

```
:10A: <any characters here>\r\n
<any characters here>\r\n
<any characters here>\r\n
.
.
.
:11A: or :12P:
```

There can be up to 10 lines between the two ":XXX:" signs (including the first row).
I need to extract (using only REGEX, no Java methods) the first one to four lines (including the first line, without the ":10A:").

Examples 1:

```
:10A: Line number 1\r\n
Line number 2\r\n
Line number 3\r\n
Line number 4\r\n
Line number 5\r\n
Line number 6\r\n
:11A:
```

Will extract:

```
Line number 1\r\n
Line number 2\r\n
Line number 3\r\n
Line number 4\r\n
```

Example 2:

```
:10A: Line number 1\r\n
Line number 2\r\n
:12P:
```

Will extract:

```
Line number 1\r\n
Line number 2\r\n
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: @Elist, this might or might not be a hint: "...only REGEX, no Java methods"

Comment: Please read the Java Regex Tutorial.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html  Then, maybe, you can code your own regexes instead of getting SO readers to do your job for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex

```
(?<=:.{3}:)(.*?(\\r?\\n)){1,4}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Description

This expression will capture the first 4 lines of text of each section.

`^:[^:]*:(.*?(?:^(?:(?!^:[^:]*:|[\r\n]|\Z).)*[\r\n\Z]*){3})`

[image]

## Expanded

- `^:[^:]*:` match the section break
- `.*?`  match the line of text on the same line as the section break
- `(?` this capture group will match an entire line which is not a section break

  - `^` match the start of the line
  - `(?:(?!^:[^:]*:|[\r\n]|\Z).)*` match all characters on the line providing they are not a section title, new line characters, or the end of the string
  - `[\r\n\Z]*` match any number of new line characters or end of string
  - `){3}` attempt to match three of those lines. Note the internal condition is auto limited and will prevent capturing more lines then a section may contain.

## Java Code Example:

**Input text**

```
:10A: Line number 1
Line number 2
Line number 3
Line number 4
Line number 5
Line number 6
:11A:Line number 1
Line number 2
Line number 3
Line number 4
:10A: Line number 1
Line number 2
:12P:Line number 1
Line number 2
```

**Code**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
class Module1{
  public static void main(String[] asd){
  String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile("^:[^:]*:(.*?(?:^(?:(?!^:[^:]*:|[\r\n]|\Z).)*[\r\n\Z]*){3})",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
  Matcher m = re.matcher(sourcestring);
  int mIdx = 0;
    while (m.find()){
      for( int groupIdx = 0; groupIdx < m.groupCount()+1; groupIdx++ ){
        System.out.println( "[" + mIdx + "][" + groupIdx + "] = " + m.group(groupIdx));
      }
      mIdx++;
    }
  }
}
```

**Matches**
This is only showing capture group 1. Capture group 0 is the entire matched string

```
$matches Array:
(
   [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  Line number 1
Line number 2
Line number 3
Line number 4

            [1] => Line number 1
Line number 2
Line number 3
Line number 4

            [2] =>  Line number 1
Line number 2

            [3] => Line number 1
Line number 2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a regex to start with:

```
:(?:.*?):((?:.*?[\r\n]){1,4})(?:.*?):(?:.*?):
```

The first matching group will return up to four lines of the text.

**Important note:** you must turn on the "dotall" option in Java like in `Pattern.compile(pStr, Pattern.DOTALL)` or a similar option (single-line mode `/.../s` in Perl or `RegexOptions.Singleline` in .NET), otherwise the regex will not work due to the fact that you are working on multiline data.

Comment: given the above regex,you don't need to use dotall option since `.` is never going to match newline because of `[\r\n]`

Comment: @Anirudh That's interesting, because I tried it in RegExr and it only worked with the to DOTALL option enabled although I thought it should work without, considering exactly the same argument that you gave.